# polynomial inverse in rings understanding

Tags: ring-theory, factoring

This problem and solution are in the book. I need help understanding the solution.

Problem: Let u be a root of the polynomial $x^3+3x+3$.  In $\mathbb Q(u)$, express $(7-2u+u^2)^{-1}$ in the form $a + bu+cu^2$

Solution: Dividing $x^3+3x+3$ by $x^2-2x+7$ gives the quotient $x+2$ and remainder -11. Thus $u^3+3u+3=(u+2)(u^2-2u+7)-11$ . So $(7-2u+u^2)^{-1}=(2/11)+(1/11)u$

My question: $1=(1/11)(u+2)(u^2-2u+7)-(1/11)(u^3+3u+3)$. And  $(1/11)(u+2)(u^2-2u+7)=1$ to get the inverse as above. But WHY?? Clearly 1= (...) - (...) sum of 2 terms, how can 1 = the first term only? What is the logic here? Please, help

Answer (score 2):

The logic is that you are not working with $x$ the variable, you are working with $u$ a complex number that satisfies $u^3+3u+3=0$.

Comment: I goooooot it. Thanks a ton. :)

Comment: You're welcome.  If you are happy with the answer, please give it the check mark.  Thank you :-)